# How to model the relation `Resource A can be associated to all resource B` when we have lots of resource B in SQL database?

Tags: sql, database-design, software-design

## Use case, for example

A promotion can be applied to all channels, or a few channels,

## Relation

many-to-many

## Question

How to model the relation `A promotion can be applied to all channels`?

## My thoughts

If we don't have too many channels, we can add every channel to their relation table, what if we have thousand of channels, what is best practice to handle this situation?

Comment: I removed the database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You should ensure you have knowlegde about all the states you want to model. For instance, "Resource A can be associated to zero, one, or many resource B's", could easily be solved by a relationship table inbetween. Then you ask "but what if Resource A should be associated with all Resource B, do I need to fill this table?", then you could for instance handle this with a simple flag on the Resource A side. But then, what if you have "Resource A can be associated with all Resource B's, except one", do you need to handle this case? All these things will dictate the solution(s) chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- channel CHN exists.
--
channel {CHN}
     PK {CHN}
```

```
-- Promotion PRO exists.
--
promotion {PRO}
       PK {PRO}
```

```
-- Promotion PRO is a global promotion.
-- (applied to all channels)
--
glob_pro {PRO}
      PK {PRO}

FK {PRO} REFERENCES promotion {PRO}
```

```
-- Promotion PRO applies to channel CHN.
--
chn_pro {CHN, PRO}
     PK {CHN, PRO}

FK1 {CHN} REFERENCES channel   {CHN}
FK2 {PRO} REFERENCES promotion {PRO}
```

It may be a case that a promotion is applied to only a few
channels, and later that promotion is declared global, that is OK.
For example:

1. Say you have ten promotions `{P1 .. P10}` and 100 channels `{C1..C100}`.
2. You apply promotion `P7` to channels `C3` and `C5` by inserting `(C3, P7)` and `(C5, P7)` into `chn_pro`.
3. Then you decide to make promotion `P7` global by inserting `(P7)` into `glob_pro`, now it applies to all channels.
4. Later, if you demote the promotion, by deleting `(P7)` from `glob_pro`, it only applies to `C3` and `C5` again.

In order to list all promotions for all channels, use a view.

```sql
-- Promotion PRO applies to channel CHN.
--
CREATE VIEW all_channel_promotions
AS
SELECT CHN, PRO FROM chn_pro

UNION

SELECT CHN, PRO
FROM channel
JOIN glob_pro on True ;
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very helpfull,  for performence reason, maybe we can add a  global flag  to promotion table itself instead of a dedeciated glob_pro table.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `promotion_channels` table (which I think you are calling "relations" but that name is vague) and add any matching channel into the table.  For a promotion that affects all channels, all channels should be added.

Why?  Because you may add channels over time.  You don't want old promotions to apply to new channels.

Of course, you could also have a "special" channel which means all channels -- perhaps with a `channel_id` of `0`.  Then any code that looks for channels can take this into account.  That is somewhat complicated and prone to error, but much of that could be hidden in views and other constructs.

But, because channels may change over time, I don't recommend that approach.